# Copying from one workbook to open workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am trying to copy an object from a closed workbook to the currently open workbook, the code I have bee experimenting with is:

```
Sub test()
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WBDest As Workbook

Set WBDest = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name)

 'Open up your first workbook, copy data
Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open("path to the folder\testbook.xlsx")
WB1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F12").Copy

'paste in second workbook
WBDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
 'Close first workbook
WB1.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

I keep getting a "subscript out of range" error with this, if I remove the WBDest info and used activeworkbook instead, it copies the object and pastes it in the same workbook as it is the activeworkbook at the time.

Could someone please guide me on this and help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: What line does the error refer to?

Comment: [you do not need to open the workbook just to get some data from it.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51662/retrieving-data-from-files-in-the-folder/51809#51809).. also go with [ADODB](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/various-ways-to-pull-data-from-another-workbook-closedopened/) it's much faster

Comment: @AndyG After trying it out it looks like his error refers to line 5: Set WBDest etc.

Comment: @114 are you sure your current workbook has been already saved?

Comment: I suspect it should be `Set WBDest = Workbooks.Open(..)`

Comment: thanks for the help guys. me how, I have used ADODB for cell data but can it be used for "paste special" objects also?

Comment: @User26601 Sorry, I'm not too familiar with ADODB - maybe someone on the PHP tag would know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by AndyG, it should be WBDest = Workbooks.Open(..).  The replacement is then:

```
Sub test()
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WBDest As Workbook

Set WBDest = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name)

 'Open up your first workbook, copy data
Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open("path to the folder\testbook.xlsx")
WB1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A7").Copy

'paste in second workbook
WBDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A7").PasteSpecial
 'Close first workbook
WB1.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Note that on the 5th line you could as easily write `WBDest = ActiveWorkbook` if the workbook is already open as you suggest.